# Re-reading binding value on Command execution

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Let's say I have a button like this:

```
<Button x:Name="DeleteItem" Content="Delete item" Height="20" Width="100" Margin="0,0,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Command="{Binding DeleteItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=MainWindowObject}"/>
```

MainWindowObject is the Window in which this button resides, so the CommandParameter binding is reading the value of the 'SelectedItem' property I made in the code-behind which looks like this:

```
public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CurrentTab)
            {
                case TabType.Author:
                    return this.AuthorGrid.SelectedItem;
                default: // BookGrid is the default grid
                    return this.BookGrid.SelectedItem;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically it should get the grid's current selected item. The reason why I just don't read the value directly using "Binding ElementName=Grid, Path=SelectedItem" or something like that is because the grid that it will choose in the switch depends on the 'CurrentTab' property, which is another property that tells me which TabItem is the active one in a TabControl.

The **problem** I'm having is that the program reads the 'SelectedItem' value once on startup and every time I call the Command it uses that old, stale value. What I need is for it to re-run the 'SelectedItem' property every time the command runs so it gets a new, fresh value.

*So basically I need to know how to update the binding's value dynamically every time the Command gets called. Anyone know how I can do something like that declaratively without making a mess in my codebehind?*

Comment: Bind your `Grids` `SelectedItem` to a Property and use it eg:  `SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem,Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would mean I'd have (lets say) 3 SelectedItem properties if I'd have 3 grids, and I'd still need to execute the code above to choose which one I need (depending on CurrentTab), so this doesn't really do what I need it to do. If I got it wrong, it would be great if you could go into more detail.

Comment: 1) Yes if you have 3 Grids, then Bind each Grids `SelectedItem` to 3 different properties. and get the value based on the property. 
2) Even you can bind the same property but the last selected will be your SelectedItem

Comment: The problem is that I need to choose the correct 'SelectedItem' depending on the value of 'CurrentTab' at the time of execution of the command (which is why I have that switch there), your answer doesn't really enable me to do that or at least I'm not understanding it correctly. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Bindings will update when the PropertyChanged event of INotifyPropertyChanged is raised, so when CurrentTab is changed, call PropertyChanged with the name "SelectedItem"

Comment: I would say create different VM for each TabItem with SelectedItem Property in VM. so that you will be able to find out which one is selected in which Tab.

Comment: @Fabis Why don't you use a valueconverter for your binding?

Comment: As clcto said you should try raise PropertyChanged. Or maybe problem doesn't lie in the SelectedItem but in the CurrentTab. Then try raise PropertyChanged when CurrentTab has changed, so SelectedItem would be informed about it.